# How to use Awk to filter rows using a column value under double quotes

Tags: unix, awk

```
"A","B",123,"C","AAB"
"A","BB",234,"CC","BA"
"AA","B",123,"CC","CBB"
"AA","BB",213,"C","CCA"
```

I want to get those rows where $1 == AA

```
 awk 'BEGIN { FS = ","; OFS = FS;} {if ($1=="AA") print}'
```

but its not working. It works if the data is **not** in double quotes.

Comment: you could also use `grep '^"AA",'`.. but it is good idea to think awk when it comes to field based processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match the literal `"` with an escape character. This is *the* straight-forward filter to match the literal `"AA"` on the first column. Since `awk` works on a `pattern { action }` basis, the condition match to see if first column is `"AA"` can be done directly without needing to use explicit `{ print }`

If the condition is met for that line, `awk` is left with a condition as `awk 1 file` on which case the line is printed.

```
awk -v FS=, '$1=="\"AA\""' file
```

Also, you can avoid escapes, by putting the match string in a variable under single-quotes and let it match the variable

```
awk -v FS=, -v m='"AA"' '$1==m' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F, '{val=$1;gsub(/\"/,"",val)} val=="AA"'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
awk -F"[\",]" '$2=="AA"'  Input_file
```

Comment: Why do you wan to do this when you can do a literal match?, don't mess with `"` as a field separator.